# Fatal error while executing cron job in Google AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

I want to execute a cron job in GAE but i got this error.I want to use app engine services without logging in to my email.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Could not json decode the token' in /base/data/home/apps/s~gcdc2013-cloud-daybook/1.371004284914522718/google-api-php-client/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:162
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/apps/s~gcdc2013-cloud-daybook/1.371004284914522718/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php(170): Google_OAuth2->setAccessToken(NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you're not running it from cron?

It looks like your either missing the service account key, or you're not loading it properly.